# Automating Django setup with Fabric: how to edit Django settings?

Tags: python, django, fabric, django-settings

I'd like to automate development environment setup for my Django apps. After looking around a bit, it seems like Fabric is the way to go. Ideally, the script would prompt for the name of the project, and then create a new Django project using django-admin.py. It'd then automate lots of things, like creating a new virtualenv, creating a new database and database user, installing some Python modules, etc. I think I can figure out how to do pretty much all of that with Fabric. The one place I'm stuck though is how to edit my Django settings. I'd like to edit the default Django settings.py to include some extra INSTALLED_APPS, and setup the database backend, database username and password, etc.

Is this possible with Fabric? Would it be better to create my own settings.py.sample file and then insert the name of the project where needed. If so, what's the best way to do that with Fabric/Python?

Comment: Consider using a project template for this kind of stuff https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django's `startproject` templates are perfect for this. Check [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#startproject-projectname-destination) out for more.

```
django-admin.py startproject --template=https://github.com/githubuser/django-project-template/archive/master.zip myproject
```

Thanks to Yuval for the tip.

If anyone's interested, I'm now using Fabric to create a new directory and virtualenv, install some required packages, and then run a command like the one above. It also creates a new DB and BitBucket repo. This script has already saved me a ton of time; I can now go from 0 to a fully running project in ~10 seconds!